# Do a dynamic allocation occurs every time an elements is inserted in a std::list container?

Tags: c++, containers, stdlist

If I insert an element into an empty `std::list` container I would expect a memory allocation to occurs in order to store my element. Now, if I remove this element and add a new one, do the allocated memory get released and reallocated upon insertion or common implementations are able to keep a pool of entries that are released (erased) so that they could be reused?

Answer (score 1):

A `std::list<>` implements a linked list data structure and thus (conceptually) allocates new memory every time an element is inserted. That being said, all of the standard container classes accept a type parameter that represents the allocator to use. With this parameter, you can change the allocator to one which simply returns pointers into  a pre-allocated memory area. Of course, if you already know how much memory you are going to need upfront, it's unclear  why you would use this type of data structure.

Comment: I need to use a list instead of a deque because I'll be inserting and one end and removing at the other end and there will be other objects with iterators to it that can't be invalidated when there are insertions or deletions. This is to implement a moving window of irregularly sampled data.

Comment: How do you intend for the iterator not to be invalidated if the item is removed? That does not make sense regardless of the data structure.

Comment: The items only get removed at the beginning of the container (older samples) and added at the end (newest samples). The iterators I talk about would have moved to a fresher element when I'm removing what I don't need anymore (very old samples).